# How can I beat level 1-25 of Aporkalypse?

Tags: aporkalypse

I'm playing level 25 of the first part of Aporkalypse (an android game).  On the left side there's a key and a target but I can't figure out how to get both of them.  I end up boxing myself in or falling down and getting stuck.

How can I solve this?  Maybe there's an extra box I can use, do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing down the box (hay bale), trying having the Death Pig jump down there.  The War Pig can stand on it when it's in physical form and shoot the target, and if you have the War Pig shoot the angel pig while the Death Pig is in spirit form it will teleport back up.  Then the hay bale is free for other uses :)